# Having errors during attempted recursive merge between two branches in git

Tags: git, github, vi

[Having errors during attempted recursive merge between two branches in git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXKaK.png)

```
Abhinavs-MBP:src Akurada$ git branch --no-merged
  master

Abhinavs-MBP:src Akurada$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'

Abhinavs-MBP:src Akurada$ git branch --no-merged
  add-scoring

Abhinavs-MBP:src Akurada$ git merge add-scoring
error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.

Abhinavs-MBP:src Akurada$ git merge add-scoring
fatal: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
Please, commit your changes before you merge.
```

Comment: Please don't put code/the important stuff in an image. Instead, write it into your question.

Comment: Abhinav, that is not the standard practice on Stackoverflow. Please provide the details of your question in here as Stackoverflow is not for helping you only but hopefully helps other with similar problem. If the external link is unreachable in the future, then this question here becomes useless for other members of this community.

Comment: the error is resulting specifically when attempting a recursive merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have vi in your system path?  Set editor with git's configuration

core.editor
By default, Git uses whatever you’ve set as your default text editor ($VISUAL or $EDITOR) or else falls back to the vi editor to create and edit your commit and tag messages. To change that default to something else, you can use the core.editor setting:

$ git config --global core.editor emacs
Now, no matter what is set as your default shell editor, Git will fire up Emacs to edit messages.

Comment: Thanks! Using emacs instead of vi worked - i dont know why but I was able to make a recursive strategy merge.